# Proving a side of a triangle is a cube.

Tags: geometry

I was given the question by one of my former students and I tried different approaches. I tried to do it geometrically and but it seems to get rather confusing pretty quickly. I tried an algebraic approach and it seems to give better results but I have problems connecting the common factor of 1 with the rest of the solution.

Proving that cos and sin are rational is relatively straightforward (I used cosine rule and since all the sides are integers then the cos needs to be a rational number) but then I get stuck.

The question is as follows:

How do I prove that at least of the sides p, q, r is a cube given the following: the side lengths p, q, r of a triangle PQR are positive integers such that the highest common factor of p, q, and r is 1 and that angle P = 3Q?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Using sine law, ${p\over q} = {\sin(3Q)\over \sin(Q)} = {3\sin(Q)-4\sin^3(Q)\over \sin(Q)} = 3-4\sin^2(Q) = 2\cos(2Q)+1$. Now ${r\over q}={\sin(4Q) \over \sin(Q)}={4\sin(Q)\cos(Q)\cos(2Q)\over \sin(Q)}=4\cos(Q)\cos(2Q)=2\cos(Q)({p\over q}-1)$, so $2\cos(Q) = {r\over q({p\over q} - 1)} = {r\over p-q}$

Using cosine law, $p^2+r^2-2pr\cos(Q)=q^2$ so $p^2+r^2-{pr^2\over p-q}=q^2$.
Simplify, $(p^2-q^2)(p-q) = r^2q$ and $(p-q)^2(p+q)=r^2q$.

Suppose $\gcd(p,q)=k$ and $p=p'k$ and $q=q'k$. Then we have $(p'-q')^2(p'+q')k^2=r^2q'$. Notice that $q'$ is coprime with $p'-q'$ and $p'+q'$, and furthermore $r$ is coprime with $k$ as $\gcd(p,q,r)=1$ is given, we can conclude $q'=k^2$. Therefore $q=k^3$.